# Process PDF files in Browser directly?

Tags: python, pdf, web-applications

I wrote a web app to extract some information from a specific format of PDF files.
When the PDF file was uploaded to the server, I use pdfminer to extract text from it, and then send the output the the user.

Is there a way Python can do to extract the information therein without uploading the file unto the server?

Comment: Is this a question about python?

Comment: I use pdfminer ( a third party library of python ) to extract information.

Comment: yes, but this question is about the browser, where you'll probably need javascript. There are [a number of javascript pdf libraries](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=javascript+pdf+library).